# Flask on IIS - Configuration settings

Tags: python-3.x, iis, wfastcgi

I am new to Python but I am finding it extremely interesting. Coming from a .NET environment, I need to host a Flask application on IIS. I did manage to host the application but I still cannot seem to wrap my head around some settings one needs to put in the web.config file.

Can you help me understand what exactly **WSGI_HANDLER** and **PYTHONPATH** do please? I did read the [wfastcgi documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wfastcgi) but I am still a bit confused.